# The rectangle is not showing up on frame when I run the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm making a face detection and recognition program. I've tried changing the stroke number and color but still get the same results. I expect to see a rectangle on the face when a face is detected or seen on the frame.

My code:

```
color = (255, 0, 0) #BGR 0-255 
stroke = 4
end_cord_x = x + w
end_cord_y = y + h
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (end_cord_x, end_cord_y), color, stroke)
subitems = smile_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in subitems:
    cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: I really need your help guys

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code is not a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you with something we cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear, but try setting `scaleFactor` and `minNeighbors` parameters in `face_cascade.detectMultiScale()` and `smile_cascade.detectMultiScale()` to detect face and smile properly.

code:

```
import cv2  

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml') 
smile_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_smile.xml')  

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

while True:  
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces: 
        color = (255, 0, 0)
        stroke = 4
        end_cord_x = x + w
        end_cord_y = y + h
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (end_cord_x, end_cord_y), color, stroke) 
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w] 
        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w] 
        smiles = smile_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 2, 20) 

        for (sx, sy, sw, sh) in smiles: 
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (sx, sy), ((sx + sw), (sy + sh)), (0, 255, 0), 2) 

    cv2.imshow('Detected Face',frame) 

    # Wait for Esc key to stop 
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: 
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Read more about how to detect face using Haar feature-based cascade classifiers from [here](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Image_Object_Detection_Face_Detection_Haar_Cascade_Classifiers.php).